# Handling COM event cancelation in VBScript

Tags: events, outlook, vbscript, wsh, cdo.message

I would like to write a script, that sends an E-Mail via our companys SMTP-Server using CDO.

First I tried to write an HTA-application for that purpose, but it became rather fiddly to make it cormfortable enough so that other people may handle it well (because of proper recipient resolving).

So now I try to use the regular Outlook-Mail mask to prepare the mail first and then catch the send-item event via VBScript to give it's content to my CDO script.

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
Dim OutlookApplication
Dim MailItem
Const olDiscard = 1
Const olMailItem = 0

Set OutlookApplication = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application", "Outlook_")
Set MailItem = OutlookApplication.CreateItem(olMailItem)
MailItem.Display

'(...) some code to add recipients, subject, text, etc... depending on the given WScript.Arguments

While Not MailItem Is Nothing
    'keep the script alive
    WScript.Sleep 1
WEnd

Function CDOSendMessage()
    'some code to send the data to our smtp server, return true if successfull
    CDOSendMessage = True
End Function

Sub Outlook_ItemSend(byVal Item, Cancel)
    If Item.body = MailItem.body Then 'Any more fail proof suggestions on how to check if it's the correct mailitem I'm handling with this event? While the script is alive, it fires for EVERY mail I send via outlook
        Cancel = True

        If CDOSendMessage() then
            Set MailItem = Nothing
            MailItem.Close olDiscard
        Else
            Cancel = False
            MsgBox "Sending message via CDO failed."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The main problem is, that Cancel = True simply does not work. Outlook will send my mail using my regular mail adress no matter what. Can you tell me, what I'm doing wrong please?

Thank you very much in advance!

Guido

Answer (score 1):

The Cancel parameter must be declared with the `ByRef` modifier.

Comment: Sadly this does not change the behavior of my script... As far as I know ByRef is the default modifier in VBScript anyway.

Comment: No, the default is ByVal.Please show your updated code.

Comment: I think I figured out, why it won't work. I had a similar situation where I tried to call an object method with a byRef-Parameter from VBS. It simply did not handle it byRef. It took me a while to find the answer (on stackoverflow actually): Passing a variable byRef requires the variable to be of the same type as the function parameter. But VBS only supports `Variant` datatype. Thats the reason why their value won't change when passed byRef to a method in MS Office. I had to write the code in powershell (which actually supports all datatypes) to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

Updated code as requested:
    Dim OutlookApplication
    Dim MailItem
    Dim CDODone: CDODone = False
    Const olDiscard = 1
    Const olMailItem = 0

```
Set OutlookApplication = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application", "Outlook_")
Set MailItem = OutlookApplication.CreateItem(olMailItem)
MailItem.UserProperties.Add "CDOFlag", 20, false, false
MailItem.Display

'(...) some code to add recipients, subject, text, etc... depending on the given WScript.Arguments

While Not CDODone Is Nothing
    'keep the script alive
    WScript.Sleep 1
WEnd
MailItem.Close olDiscard
Function CDOSendMessage()
    'some code to send the data to our smtp server, return true if successfull
    CDOSendMessage = True
End Function

Sub Outlook_ItemSend(byVal Item, byRef Cancel)
    If Not Item.UserProperties.Find(CDOFlag) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True

        If CDOSendMessage() then
            CDODOne = True
        Else
            Cancel = False
            MsgBox "Sending message via CDO failed."
            WScript.Quit
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```