# COM (MS Office) eventing in Powershell

Tags: powershell, events, outlook, com, cdo.message

This question is strongly related to my prior one here: [Handling COM event cancelation in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54146978/handling-com-event-cancelation-in-vbscript/54154111#54154111)

I would like to write a script, that sends an E-Mail via our companys SMTP-Server using CDO.

First I tried to write an HTA-application for that purpose, but it became rather fiddly to make it cormfortable enough so that other people may handle it well (because of proper recipient resolving).

So now I try to use the regular Outlook-Mail mask to prepare the mail first and then catch the send-item event via Powershell to give it's content to my CDO script. I tried it via VBScript before (see link above) but that doesn't seem to work as intended.

I'm rather new to powershell-scripting but in the past I already got things to work that wouldn't work in VBScript so I hope to get my problem solved with it again. Right now, my script looks like this:

```
$WSH = new-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell"
$Outlook = new-Object -ComObject "Outlook.Application"
$olMailItem = 0

register-objectevent -InputObject $Outlook -EventName "ItemSend"

$MailObject = $Outlook.CreateItem($olMailItem)
$MailObject.Display()

function Outlook_ItemSend([object] $Item, [ref] $Cancel)
{
    $Cancel = $TRUE
    $WSH.PopUp("Event worked")
    return $Null
}
```

I didn't come as far as I was hoping yet, because I can't figure out how to fire the event at all. You can find plenty of examples for `register-objectevent` online, but everytime it appears to be very very specific for some special COM object. I couldn't find any example to register an MS-Office COM event that requires parameters so far...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an event, you can display the message modally - call `MailItem.Display` and pass `true` as the parameter.

Comment: Thats actually a good hint, but sadly didn't do the trick... When I display the mail as modal, my script pauses (good so far) but the moment that me (or another user) hits "send", the mail gets sent out regularly before my code continues its execution. So it's too late to handle the mail any further.

Comment: Oh, are you trying to modify the message after the user clicks the Send button but before it is actually sent? Does the event still not fire?

Comment: Yes, I actually want to cancel the ItemSend-Event because I have written another function utilizing CDO to send my E-Mail via our SMTP-server to actually make it look like some system-generated E-Mail. I want to create event based E-Mails but give the user the opportunity to still edit the contents of the mail.

So when the user hits the send-button, I want the E-Mail to hide instead, hand over all its contents to my CDO-script (to send it from there instead) and then destroy the outlook mail afterwards without actually beeing sent by the user.

Comment: And yes, the event still does not actually fire. It rather crashes whenever I hit the send-button. I created an `$Action = {Write-Host 'TestEvent'}` to give it to the `Register-ObjectEvent` but that doesn't help either.

Comment: I don't know why the event does not fire, sorry - I am not a PS expert.